# Prefix filename in for all the files in directory for ls (list command) output

Tags: bash, shell

I have downloaded some files into a directory.

I want to prefix all the files with 001, 002,.....050 like the numbering order

But I wanted the files to be in the File created Order

`ls -c` is listing the files in created order
[image]

Prefix should be in the following manner

- 001_Adding Methods ......
- 002_Breaking Our App ......

I have tried

```
for i in "$(ls -c)";
  do
   echo i;
done;
```

`echo i` is printing the file names that is okay. But i want to prefix autogenetated number in this format 001,002,003,.....

Comment: Don't use pictures for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for current dir :

```
c=0
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%A@ %f\n' |
sort -n -k1 |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo mv "${line#* }" "$(printf '%03d_%s\n' $((++c)) "${line#* }")"
done
```

And please, [don't parse ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Note: remove `echo` for `mv` command when your tests becomes OK

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a loop, let, and printf for the padding:

```
a=1
for i in *; do
  new=$(printf "%03d" "$a") #03 pad to length of 3
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new$i"
  let a=a+1
done
```

using the -i flag prevents automatically overwriting existing files.

Comment: OP asked files sorted by creation date